# display vars_prompt value in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a vars_prompt in my ansible site.yml file.  The prompt shows up in the command prompt but the response typed by the user does not.  Is there a command to display the response typed by the user (when they are typing in the response) - not just via a debug message.

```
vars_prompt:
    - name: "TEST"
      prompt: "Specify test value"
      default: "local"
      private: no
```

I would like the user response to show up in the command prompt as they are typing the response.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hide the input you'd use;

```
private: yes
```

Alternatively, to show the input as the user is typing it you would use;

```
private: no
```

I see that you have it in your playbook already. I also tested your yml and confirmed that I can see what I am typing as I am inputting the "test value" field.

Please clarify the issue because as it stands, your playbook does exactly what you're describing that you want it to do.

Comment: thanks @avalon - unfortunately, the prompt shows up in the command prompt but not the value the end user is typing.  Any thoughts (running ansible v2.1.0.0 on ubuntu 14)

Comment: I tested your playbook. When I am prompted for "Specify test value", I enter random characters. I am able to see the characters I am typing, as I type them. Is this the desired function? If not you'll need to expand on what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: I cannot see the characters as I am typing them - can you please share your ansible version and OS.

Comment: ansible 2.1.1.0 and Ubuntu 16.

Comment: I had a typo - private was in upper case in my original file, not lower case & that was causing the issue

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. When you post questions just copy/paste directly from your original file - it'll help troubleshooting in cases like this.